# empty file in force download - what is wrong?

Tags: php, download

i using the following code to force download files in php

```
<?PHP
    $id =$_GET['id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE  id = '" . $id . "' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $file_name = $row[url]; //  "wwyypyv6.pdf"
        $file_type = $row[type]; // "application/pdf"
        $file_url = 'http://emfhal.hostech.co.il/upload/' . $file_name;
    }
        header("Content-Type: " . $file_type);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name");
        readfile($file_url);
        exit();


    ?>
```

When I use this code to download this pdf file (only used for testing purposes), I open the downloaded , and all it gives me is an file empty. i tried it in chrome. opening it with windows and google chrome, it says that it can't display the pdf file because it is empty???

Comment: @aligarian you dont see the code?

Comment: You missing many required headers. Also If you get an empty file in most cases it seems filepath is given incorrect.

Comment: @Rikesh i edit now... i think maybe the problem that its in a dir "upload/"

Comment: Check the path you getting in `$file_url` & run that in url.

Comment: @Rikesh i cheack the url few times...

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution:

```
// grab the requested file's name
$file_name = $_GET['file'];

// make sure it's a file before doing anything!
if(is_file($file_name)) {

    /*
        Do any processing you'd like here:
        1.  Increment a counter
        2.  Do something with the DB
        3.  Check user permissions
        4.  Anything you want!
    */

    // required for IE
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }

    // get the file mime type using the file extension
    switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
        case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
        default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
    }
    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($file_name);       // push it out
    exit();
```

}

Comment: its not working... the same problem i try want you write in find it from google...

Comment: Check if the file exist and your php file has encoding "UTF-8 without BOM."

Comment: Please echo out your path and check in the browser url + path, and see if the file downloadable frm there.

Comment: @FalkS. http://emfhal.hostech.co.il/upload/wwyypyv6.pdf .. you knew maybe about another way to force download?

Comment: This single line ended 5 hours of hair pulling!:
'default: $mime = 'application/force-download';'

Answer (score 0):

Use relative or absolute path for the local file being read, or if using http then enable the fopen wrapper for it:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

> This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing
>   URL object like files. Default wrappers are provided for the access of
>   remote files using the ftp or http protocol, some extensions like zlib
>   may register additional wrappers.

Add/modify this line in your php.ini file:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true); you say to paste this to my code?